# ggplot y axis is supposed to be real-valued continuous and is instead binary 1-0

Tags: r, ggplot2

My plot is supposed to look like this.  This is what my coworker says he gets when he runs my code (continuous values).

[image: ElFlow plot correct]

But when I run my code I get this.  All values are 1.00 except for a few zeros.

[image: E1Flow plot incorrect]

Here is my code. E1Fow is numeric data type.

```
ggplot(subset(sdf2, DateTime < "2019-7-20 04:40:56" & DateTime > "2019-6-4 04:40:56")) +
    geom_line(aes(DateTime, E1Flow,group=1)) +
    geom_point(aes(DateTime, E1Flow), col = "#f68060") +
    labs(x="", y = "Flow Rate, bbl/day", title = "E1") +
    scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 day", labels = date_format("%b %d")) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text = element_text( hjust = 1,size = 8, face = "bold", colour = 'black')) +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 10,colour = 'black'),plot.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 10, face = "bold"))
```

This is the output of dput(head(sdf2)):

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1559520000, 1559520000, 1559520000, 
1559520000, 1559520000, 1559520000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), DateTime = structure(c(1559553430, 1559553731, 1559554031, 
1559554332, 1559554632, 1559554932), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Rink1Flow = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), Rink2Flow = c(7761.557129, 7761.557129, 
7761.557129, 7761.557129, 7737.226074, 7761.557129), E1Flow = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Rink1BHP = c(3084.545654, 
3067.445557, 3059.159668, 3050.7854, 3042.701172, 3034.56543), 
    Rink2BHP = c(3342.094971, 3343.468262, 3344.161865, 3345.700195, 
    3345.699219, 3346.436035), E1BHP = c(2663.33374, 2663.418457, 
    2663.493896, 2663.362793, 2663.514404, 2663.510498), Rink1BHT = c(112.818283, 
    112.907936, 112.945946, 112.980003, 113.01516, 113.045921
    ), Rink2BHT = c(103.476433, 103.672081, 103.851364, 104.025063, 
    104.170158, 104.305145), E1BHT = c(178.108063, 178.107178, 
    178.104538, 178.106735, 178.107178, 178.108063), Rink1BHD = c(1172.153801, 
    1172.134131, 1173.101217, 1173.863411, 1174.750999, 1175.915599
    ), Rink2BHD = c(1166.190654, 1166.629121, 1167.672426, 1168.28382, 
    1169.314012, 1169.7115), E1BHD = c(1141.078398, 1141.071841, 
    1140.954643, 1140.765324, 1140.403077, 1140.530929)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The tail end of E1Flow is (...,1,1,1,1,1,1,1).  I think for some reason it's reading the wrong column because in the data file the previous column is discrete 1s or 0s.

```
> length(unique(nf4$E1Flow))
[1] 3
> summary(nf4$E1Flow)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
0.0000  1.0000  1.0000  0.9998  1.0000  1.0000    2743
```

Comment: Help us help you: Provide a [mcve]. In particular, it will probably be hard for someone to reproduce your problem without your data. You can use the R command `dput()`, or `dput(head())` to get an easy representation of your data for people to cut and paste into their code editor to put your data into their R session. Please [edit] your question to include the output of the R command `dput(sdf2)` (or `dput(head(sdf2))` for a subset, which would be more reasonable, but may or may not result in the ability to replicate the problem))

Comment: Sorry, the first rows of `E1Flow` are all `NA`; maybe try `dput(tail(sdf2))`? I didn't realize you'd have all missingness at the beginning of the dataframe

Comment: I think your issue is your data. What does `length(unique(sdf2$E1Flow))` and `summary(sdf2$E1Flow)` return?

Comment: Yeah, it's reading the wrong column and I don't know why.

Comment: Your code plots E1flow but this column only contains NA. You filter for dates which appear to remove all rows. Could you give us a working sample?

Comment: @NickKnapp It appears that either `E1Flow` isn't the column you need, or at some point you (probably inadvertently) overwrote the `E1Flow` column to contain only 0, 1, and NA. We can't be sure how that happened without seeing your whole `.Rhistory`, but my advice would be 1st to check the file as it's saved on disk. Does it have the correct data? If not, you likely overwrote the file on disk with the unwanted changes. Then you'd need to recover the old version of the file. It sounds like your coworker has such a version. Could be other options too depending on your situation (git, etc.)